# In Wolf Among Us what is the significance of the cigarettes found throughout the game

Tags: video-games, fables-comics

There are a number of cigarette butts found throughout the game.  The always seem to be "Huff and Puff" brand, and are left near important events.
Bigby also appears to smoke that brand.  Nerrisa at some point tells you that not many smoke the brand.  She seems to be leading you around all game, and it seems like one more hint towards the thing she wants you to know.

Does this have anything to do with the end of the game, where she very strongly tries to tell you something else is going on?

I know that many of these things can be speculations, but even just knowing everywhere the cigarettes of that brand appear, that are not Bigby's would help

Comment: While this question is appropriate to ask here, you may have more luck on: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/ Side note: Huff ad Puff is certainly a play on words. As the big bad wolf in the fairy tale did "Huff and puff and blow your house down."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are three important things related to the *Huff n'Puff* cigarettes:

1. They are Bigby's favourite brand and (as stated in the comment from S. Fruggiero) their name is a reference to the  *Three Little Pigs* fairy tale. As far as I remember not only Nerissa, but also other characters mention that it's an inferior brand and there aren't many people smoking it.
2. They can be found on the murder scene in the hotel where Beauty works, which means that the killer smokes them (so it's a clue). Later [Georgie can be seen smoking them](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BK-VA9imlCg&t=279), which can help you identifying him as a killer (or at least the "executioner").
3. They are important to the famous Faith/Nerissa theory. There are several variations of it, but basically the idea is that Nerissa was glamoured Faith or Faith was glamoured Nerissa or even both during (a part of) the game events. The importance of the cigarettes comes from the fact that Faith smokes *Huff n'Puff* in Episode 1. Later Nerissa refuses it, but in Episode 5 she is happy to accept a *Huff n'Puff* from Bigby. You will find more information about it without a problem, for example check [this link](http://www.reddit.com/r/TheWolfAmongUs/comments/2a79fr/spoiler_s_telltale_hints_the_truth_behind_the/) as the cigarettes part is mentioned there.